# storing SQL queries in a dictionary?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

What is the best way to do a stored procedure for MySQL queries in python?

I really need to be able to access the key name which is why i went down the route of using a dictionary. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
reports = { 'z_report': """
SELECT * FROM calculation1
WHERE owner = "z"
AND calculation1.`Last Seen` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
;
"""
'y_report': """
SELECT * FROM calculation1
WHERE owner = "y"
AND calculation1.`Last Seen` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
;
"""
'x_report': """
SELECT * FROM calculation1
WHERE owner = "x"
AND calculation1.`Last Seen` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
;
"""
'master_report': """
SELECT * FROM calculation1
WHERE calculation1.`Last Seen` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
;
"""
```

p.s. i already know this is vuln to SQLi, i'm just trying to get a prototype up first.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: those aren't stored procedures. they're just sql query strings in a dictionary...

Comment: OK I am new to SQL so I will rename the question

Comment: Why don't you put each query in a separate function and then add the functions (the functions, not their names) to the dictionary?

By the way, stored procedures are stored on the database so these are not stored procs.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html) with a basic example found here [MySQL Python Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/). You would continue to use a dictionary, except this time, the key (name, index, etc) will reference a prepared statement. You benefit in terms of security and performance as a result too.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html, you can store as queries as values no problem, the docs give you lots of good example of using the python mysql connect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying your approach is good or bad. I'll just address your specific question: you could put each query in its own function e.g.

```
def do_z_report():
    # call MySQL with specific z_report query

def do_y_report():
    # call MySQL with specific y_report query
```

Add these to your dictionary:

```
queries = {'z_report': do_z_report, 'y_report' : do_y_report}
```

Call the functions:

```
queries['z_report']()
queries['y_report']()
```

Comment: Why would you store the function names in a dict instead of just calling the function by name?

Comment: because the question was how to store the queries in a dictionary and it seems "cleaner" to store the functions there and maintain the queries in the functions - well, actually - how to access by key name

Comment: I don't see the logic, if you are going to use a dict then store the queries in the dict if you are going to use  functions just call the function.

Comment: The asker probably has some reason for wanting to use a key - I don't know what that reason is. I once did for a command-line menu. The menu number was the key. On the other hand, the advantage of putting a query in a function is clear: it's easy to read, change, parameterize. The code that uses the key to access the query is clearly separated from the code that calls the database. In other words, it provides a small layer of abstraction simple enough to implement for prototyping.